# Getting the youngest and oldest person of an Array JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Well, I'd like to get the `oldest` and the `youngest` persons of an array in Javascript.

This is my code:

```
persons.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.age - b.age;
})

console.log(persons[0])
console.log(persons[99])

persons.filter(function(item){ 
    return item.age >= persons[0].age 
})
```

The array has 99 elements so the first is the `youngest` and the last is the `oldest`. The problem is that if two persons have the same age I only get one of them. How do I have to change the code to get all persons with the `youngest` age and the persons with the `oldest` age?

Comment: Looks like your `filter` approach would work, but sorting with `a.age - b.age` sorts the array in ascending order. `persons.filter(({age}) => age <= persons[0].age)` would find the youngest persons, using `<=`, not `>=`. `age >= persons.at(-1).age` would find the oldest ones.

Comment: If `persons` has 99 elements then `persons[99]` is undefined.

Comment: @WaisKamal I also noticed that, but the question doesn’t appear to focus on that; just looks like an example. In real code, `persons[persons.length - 1]` or `persons.at(-1)` should be used anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You can check which value of the array is the largest, then use `Array.filter()` to keep only the items that match that value:

```js
var persons = [
  4,2,8,19,4,13,2,8,19,2
];

var max = Math.max(...persons);
var maxValues = persons.filter(item => item == max);

var min = Math.min(...persons);
var minValues = persons.filter(item => item == min);

console.log(maxValues);
console.log(minValues);
```

**Edit:** if you have an array of objects, you might want to use a slightly different approach:

```js
var persons = [
  {name: "a", age: 4},
  {name: "b", age: 2},
  {name: "c", age: 8},
  {name: "d", age: 19},
  {name: "e", age: 4},
  {name: "f", age: 13},
  {name: "g", age: 2},
  {name: "h", age: 8},
  {name: "i", age: 19},
  {name: "j", age: 2}
];

var max = Math.max(...persons.map(person => person.age));
var maxValues = persons.filter(person => person.age == max);

var min = Math.min(...persons.map(person => person.age));
var minValues = persons.filter(person => person.age == min);

console.log(maxValues);
console.log(minValues);
```

Comment: while this answer is correct (no superfluous sorting), you might want to adapt it to the actual use case (array of objects with the "age" property).

Comment: Thanks for your note. I will edit accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Since your query is

> The problem is that if two persons have the same age I only get one
> of them. How do I have to change the code to get all persons with the
> youngest age and the persons with the oldest age.

```
 persons = persons.sort(function(a, b) {
     return a.age - b.age;
 })

 let youngest  = persons.filter(function(item){ 
   return item.age == persons[0].age ;
 })  

 let oldest = persons.filter(function(item){ 
   return item.age == persons[persons.length - 1].age ;
 })
```